# I want to run two functions at same time

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have tried all the solutions of old questions but situation is as it is... 
Function1 is as follows

```
def fun1():
    subprocess("Something in there")
```

And Function2

```
def fun2():
    fun_from_another_file()
```

And running is like

```
def run():
    p1 = Process(target=fun1)
    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=fun2)
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

They are supposed to run at a time but second function works only after first function completes its execution...
Please help... 
I am newbie at Python

Comment: For future reference, read [mcve].  Post code that runs and reproduces a problem.  There are a number of reasons the code above doesn't even execute.

Comment: Multiprocessing can start up slow...slow enough that if the first function is fast enough it finishes before the 2nd starts to execute.  Add a small sleep to the functions as my answer shows to truly see the parallelism.  The overhead of multiprocessing can cancel any gains parallelism may give you if the jobs aren't long enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example with corrections:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def fun1(): # need parentheses here to declare a no-parameter function
    for i in range(5):
        print(f'func1: {i}')
        # multiprocessing starts up slow, so the first function could finish before
        # The second processes is up and running.  Slow down a bit to see parallelism.
        time.sleep(.1)

def fun2():  # need parentheses here
    for i in range(5):
        print(f'func2: {i}')
        time.sleep(.1)

def run():  # need parentheses here
    p1 = Process(target=fun1)
    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=fun2)
    p2.start()  # need parentheses here to call the function.

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

# Required on some OSes for multiprocessing to work properly.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run() # need to actually call the run() function.
```

Output:

```
func1: 0
func2: 0
func1: 1
func2: 1
func1: 2
func2: 2
func1: 3
func2: 3
func1: 4
func2: 4
```

Comment: Yeah... That was the errors I knew... Changed the program but no luck

Comment: @KunalChikte You are using this *exact* code?  This is tested, working code in a Windows cmd.exe terminal. Run it in a terminal and not an IDE.  Multiprocessing doesn't always play nice with IDEs.  Also, what exactly does "no luck" mean? Edit your question and post your exact code, and full tracebacks of any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You have not called `start` on `p2`. You have just accessed the function without calling it, which returns a function object that is not used anywhere. Replace with `p2.start()`